# Http response erroring out when trying to read response from server

Tags: c#, flutter, .net-core, xmlhttprequest, flutter-web

I'm having difficulties on retrieving data from my server. I activated CORS and set up my call properly(already tested it with postman). I'm sending the post request to my server, method is being hit but when returning and trying to read the response on the client side, the SDK fails.

[image]

This is the error I'm getting on the console.

[image]

Am I missing something here? do I have to use another plugin for the htttp calls in web environment?

Answer (score 0):

Error information is incomplete, in which line do you get error?

I assume your uri and some other thing are ok.

change filtereDto to:

```
Map<String,dynamic> filterDto={
 'date':'2020-02-07....',
 'countryId':'1' // string number
}
```

And you dont need to :

`json.encode(filterDto)`

in post call, only filterDto is enough

```
... body: filterDto ...
```

Comment: I do need the encoding. Already  tried your approach and was not able to hit my controller in he server side. Fails when returning the response from server. It is here when fails "var response = await http...." Call  is being made but when getting the response fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Cors was being enabled on my server side incorrectly. Order activating Cors is critical for configurations to be applied properly in a .Net core app.

This is how is done. First activate Cors and then MVC.

[image]

Hope it helps anyone who is struggling with the same thing.